# Why is my Interface Builder layout collapsing to the leading margin?

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder, uistoryboard, xcode9

I have an iOS storyboard with a scene laid out as follows:

```
Container View
  Scroll View
    Content View (UIView)
      Stack View
        Label
        Text View
        Label
        ...
        Table View
        ...
```

Interface Builder doesn't give me any warnings, but there must be some x-axis ambiguity, because every so often when I make a change to the constraints everything collapses to a skinny line along the leading margin:

[image: All views reduced to a skinny line]

If I change any layout setting, it pops back. When I run the app after the layout has collapsed, the runtime layout still looks fine: it only affects Interface Builder. However, I'm also worried that there is an underlying layout problem that's manifesting in other issues now.

**Update: Submitted Radar**

Since Interface Builder isn't reporting any issues with my constraints in the designer and Xcode doesn't see any runtime issues when I open the runtime debugger, I reported a Radar, as @matt suggested in comments below. Please dupe it if you're seeing the same issue:

rdar://[37495719](https://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=4999623638777856)

Comment: When you run the app and "the runtime layout still looks fine", what happens if you then switch to the View Debugger? Is there an exclamation mark at the top right? If not, nothing's wrong.

Comment: @matt Thanks, it's saying the scrollable content size is ambiguous for my top-level scroll view. I forgot about the runtime issue reporting in Xcode.

Comment: Well, that's certainly bad. I'm a little surprised that IB itself doesn't warn about this, but it's a serious issue for your interface. The implication, if I understand correctly, would be that the Content View either is not pinned correctly to the surrounding Scroll View or is not itself sized by internal constraints.

Comment: @matt The runtime issue was actually something else I'd introduced (and it wasn't showing up in IB because I had a placeholder intrinsic height there, but the intrinsic height wasn't defined at runtime). So I'm left with no design- _or_ run-time issues.

Comment: Excellent! So if Xcode is still misbehaving (Interface Builder keeps collapsing the interface in the canvas), and there's no runtime corollary, you've found an Xcode bug and should report it to Apple.